# How to convert solution from ParabolicCylinderD to Bessel functions?

Tags: differential-equations, special-functions

I am trying to verify my manual solution to an ODE. The solution I got is in terms of Bessel functions. Maple gives the same solution.

Mathematica gives the solution in terms of [`ParabolicCylinderD`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParabolicCylinderD.html) which I have not used before and I am not familiar with.

I am assuming both solutions are mathematically equivalent.

But I am not able to transform the solution from `ParabolicCylinderD` to Bessel functions. I tried `FunctionExpand` and tried `MeijerGReduce`, but no luck.

```
ode = y''[x] + x^2 *y[x] == 0;
sol = DSolve[ode, y[x], x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

While in Maple

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This is what I tried in Mathematica

```
 FunctionExpand[sol]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 MeijerGReduce[FunctionExpand[sol], x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And I do not know what to do next.  Any suggestions?

Mathematica 12.0 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "12.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

ode = y''[x] + x^2*y[x] == 0;

sol = DSolve[ode, y, x][[1]]

(* {y -> Function[{x}, 
   C[2] ParabolicCylinderD[-(1/2), (-1 + I) x] + 
    C[1] ParabolicCylinderD[-(1/2), (1 + I) x]]} *)
```

Verifying that `sol` satisfies `ode`

```
ode /. sol // FullSimplify

(* True *)

y1[x_] = y[x] /. sol;
```

The Maple solution you gave is

```
y2[x_] = C[3] Sqrt[x] BesselJ[1/4, x^2/2] +
   C[4] Sqrt[x] BesselY[1/4, x^2/2];
```

Verifying that `y2` satisfies the ode

```
ode /. y -> y2 // FullSimplify

(* True *)
```

Equate the functions (`y1` and `y2`) and their derivatives at `x = 0` to find the relations between the arbitrary constants.

```
const = Solve[{
     (Limit[y1[x], x -> 0, Direction -> "FromAbove"] // Simplify) ==
      Limit[y2[x], x -> 0, Direction -> "FromAbove"],
     (y1'[0] // Simplify) ==
      (Limit[y2'[x], x -> 0, Direction -> "FromAbove"] // FullSimplify)}, 
      {C[1], C[2]}][[1]] // FullSimplify

(* {C[1] -> -((2^(1/4) (C[3] + (2 - I) C[4]))/Sqrt[π]), 
 C[2] -> (2^(1/4) (C[3] - I C[4]))/Sqrt[π]} *)
```

Rewriting the arbitrary constants in `y1`

```
y3[x_] = (y1[x] /. const // FunctionExpand // FullSimplify)

(* Sqrt[x] (-Sqrt[2] BesselJ[-(1/4), x^2/2] C[4] + 
   BesselJ[1/4, x^2/2] (C[3] + C[4])) *)
```

Verifying that `y3` satisfies the ode

```
ode /. y -> y3 // FullSimplify

(* True *)
```

`y3` expresses the solution in terms of Bessel functions although in a slightly different form than that provided by Maple.

**EDIT:** Verifying that `y2` and `y3` are equal

```
y2[x] == y3[x] // FullSimplify

(* True *)
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's a way to see the solution in Bessel function format:

```
Simplify[FunctionExpand[Activate[MeijerGReduce[FunctionExpand[
         DSolveValue[y''[x] + x^2 y[x] == 0, y[x], x]], x]]]]
   ((-1 - I) Sqrt[2 π] x BesselJ[1/4,x^2/2] (C[1] + I C[2]) +
    2 Sqrt[π] Sqrt[x^2] BesselJ[-(1/4), x^2/2] (C[1] + C[2]))/(2 2^(3/4) (x^2)^(1/4))

Collect[%, _C, FullSimplify @* FunctionExpand @* FullSimplify]
   (Sqrt[π] Sqrt[x] (Sqrt[2] BesselJ[-(1/4), x^2/2] -
                     (1 + I) BesselJ[1/4, x^2/2]) C[1])/(2 2^(1/4)) +
   (Sqrt[π] Sqrt[x] (Sqrt[2] BesselJ[-(1/4), x^2/2] +
                     (1 - I) BesselJ[1/4, x^2/2]) C[2])/(2 2^(1/4))
```

Of note is that the solution is expressed as a linear combination of Bessel functions of the first kind of both positive and negative orders; this is fine and still consistent with the Maple solution, because the Bessel function of the second kind can be [expressed as a linear combination of Bessel functions of the first kind](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.2.E3) for noninteger orders. If you want to see the solution in that format, you can do the following:

```
% /. BesselJ[n_?Internal`SyntacticNegativeQ, z_] :> 
Cos[n π] BesselJ[-n, z] + Sin[n π] BesselY[-n, z] // Simplify
   -1/2 (Sqrt[π] Sqrt[x] (BesselY[1/4, x^2/2] (C[1] + C[2]) +
         I BesselJ[1/4, x^2/2] (C[1] + (1 + 2 I) C[2])))/2^(1/4)
```

Comment: It is a very interesting solution. It would be very helpful if you kindly comment on the idea behind.

Comment: I'm basically exploiting the fact that the appropriate cases of `MeijerG[]` automagically expand to `BesselJ[]`.